# Hosting Geodatabase on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, esri-geodatabase

I have a simple Geodatabase in access format. I'd really like to host this database on an ArcGIS Server through one of their services.

The idea is that my users would be able to connect to this Geodatabase to look at both their features, and their databases, and then relate them. I do not want to allow editing of the database, just viewing purposes.

If at all possible, I'd really like to stay away from using ArcGIS Engine Runtime on the client side.

What might be the best service I can run? And does anyone have a good example of how to connect to that service to extract the database information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would migrate the data into a [file geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_file_geodatabase/003n0000007m000000/).  Next, I would create an mxd with one layer in it for each featureclass in the geodatabase.  Finally, I would [publish](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00530000003n000000.htm) the mxd as a mapservice.

For the client, instead of using arcengine, download one of Esri's [free web mapping sdks](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/web/web-apis) (either javascript, flex or silverlight).  You tagged your question with c#, so I suggest silverlight.

[Publish the web application](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#/Getting_Started/016600000004000000/) so that it can be accessed using a browser.

Comment: This is very good information that is getting me started. Do you per chance know where or how to display the tables/related tables within a GeoDatabase through the published web application?

Comment: This [sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#QueryWithoutMap) could be adapted to use tables (and not just layers) that are in the mxd published used by the mapservice. You can also [query related records](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/queryrelatedrecords.html).

Comment: Oops, forgot the link for the [table/layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/layer.html)